# Can one REGISTER request contain multiple To Header Fields and what would be the scenarios?

Tags: sip, pjsip, jain-sip

Can we have multiple "To" header in any SIP request/response?

Answer (score 1):

In [rfc3261](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3261), defining SIP, multiple To headers are not allowed.

The interesting part is from Section 7.3 Header Fields

> SIP header fields are similar to HTTP header fields in both syntax
> and semantics.  In particular, SIP header fields follow the [H4.2]
> definitions of syntax for the message-header and the rules for
> extending header fields over multiple lines.  However, the latter is
> specified in HTTP with implicit whitespace and folding.  This
> specification conforms to RFC 2234 [10] and uses only explicit
> whitespace and folding as an integral part of the grammar.
>
> [H4.2] also specifies that multiple header fields of the same field
> name whose value is a comma-separated list can be combined into one
> header field.  That applies to SIP as well, but the specific rule is
> different because of the different grammars.  Specifically, any SIP
> header whose grammar is of the form
>
> ```
>   header  =  "header-name" HCOLON header-value *(COMMA header-value)
> ```

Because the To header Augmented BNF does not contains COMMA, it means To can only be added once:

> ```
> To        =  ( "To" / "t" ) HCOLON ( name-addr
>              / addr-spec ) *( SEMI to-param )
> ```

The full Augmented BNF, which describe the rules, is available in [Section 25](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3261#section-25)